# The Integer dividing system issues in php

Tags: php

I got an issue in Integer dividing script.
What I want is,
If we divide 8 into 3 parts. It should show all rounded figures.
like, 3,3,2 If we SUM these 3. it will be 8.

But The Following script is dividing with some difference.
It divides 2,2,4. It is also 8. But I like the above 1. Can any one help in this case please.
Here is the code.

```
$numbertodivise = 8;
$no = 3;

$intnumber = intval($numbertodivise / $no);
$rem = $numbertodivise % $no;
$array = [];

for($i=1;$i<=$no;$i++) {
    if($i==$no) {
        $array[] = $intnumber + $rem;
    } else {
        $array[] = $intnumber;
    }
}

print_r($array);
```

its out put is

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 2 [2] => 4 )
```

Kindly Help me to make it like this

```
Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 3 [2] => 2 )
```

8 is not a fixed integer. It will by dynamic.. 8,9,19,22, 88, 9888, any digit it could be.

Comment: Use `ceil()` instead of `intval()` so it rounds up instead of down.

Comment: What output should be if we put `$numbertodivis = 1;` and `$no = 3;`?

Comment: @Justinas this outputs `Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 1 )`

Comment: @Barmar I tried `ceil()` It disturbed all the output. 
For the 8/3 it gave output `Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 3 [2] => 5 )`

Comment: @MuhammadBaberZaman So why in one example it should be bigger numbers in begin of array, but in another in the end of array? Why it's not `1, 0, 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** *changed the`$turn` to `$no` in for loop*.
You can use this for any number.

```
<?php
    $numbertodivide = 8;
    $no = 3;
    $array = [];
    $added=0;//initialize the variable to track added number to make the given number divisible
    while($numbertodivide%$no){
        $numbertodivide+=1;
        $added++;
    }
    $turn=$numbertodivide/$no;//get how many times we have to repeat the divider to get the given number
    for($i=0;$i<$no-1;$i++){
        $array[]=$turn;
    }
    $array[]=$turn-$added;//trim the added number from the last input of the number.
?>
```

Comment: If i increase number. like 8 to 13. and divider 3 it shows like this
`Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 5 [2] => 5 [3] => 5 [4] => 3 )`

Comment: @MuhammadBaberZaman sorry for the typing error i have edited the answer go back and check it and let me know by up voting. i changed `$turn` to `$no`. that's how it should be. This will work when you changed both number of the divider and dividend.

Comment: Perfect Working Now.. Lovely

Answer (score 0):

`intval()` rounds down. You want to round up, so use `ceil()`.

```
$intnumber = ceil($numbertodivise / $no);
$rem = $numbertodivise % $intnumber;

$array = array_fill(0, $no, $intnumber);
if ($rem != 0) {
    $array[count($array)-1] = $rem;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, This also did not worked 
if i make number 13 and 3 to divide. 
It shows this 
`Array ( [0] => intnumber [1] => intnumber [2] => 3 )`

Comment: Typo, left out a `$`.. Now it's `[5, 5, 3]`

Answer (score 0):

Without the need of loops. Using your variables:

```
$count = ceil($numbertodivise / $no);
$rem = $numbertodivise - ($no * ($count-1));
$array = array_fill(0,$count-1,$no);
$array[] = $rem;
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 2
)
```

Comment: But If i do 13 into 3 parts. it makes 4 output values. we need 3 parts of out put.

Comment: for 13, it made 4 outputs. 3,3,3,1 it should 4,4,5

Comment: When I did `$numbertodivise = 13; $no = 3;` I got 5,5,3 which is according to your question. 3,3,2 is highest, highest, remainder. 5,5,3 is also the same.